# How to get IE version info in Winform?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

I am developing an winform application in .NET framework 3.5, using C#.

In the application I need to display the IE version number, installed on the machine on which it runs. How can I do that, can anybody tell me?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can read the version from the registry:

```
var ieVersion = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer").GetValue("Version");
```

Comment: Sorry Alex Aza, I am new to Stack Overflow, so I was not aware of that. Thanks for your help, it solved my problem. :)

Comment: @Bibhu - no problem. Welcome aboard!

Comment: Warning: The format of this string might not be what you expect. `9.10` is IE10 and `9.11` is IE11.

Comment: Also you may want to use 'svcVersion' instead of 'Version'. For IE 10 and 11 it shows right version (as in about) and for versions below it has same value as 'Version'.

Comment: string ver = (new WebBrowser()).Version.ToString();

Answer (score 9):

With Windows 8 you should use the "svcVersion" rather than the "Version" key. Otherwise it will report that IE 9 is installed instead of IE 10. Possibly also the case with Windows 7 if you have upgraded to IE10 (I have IE 9 installed so I can't say for sure).

Answer (score 4):

I think this may help:

```
private string GetIEVersion()
{
    string key = @"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer";
    RegistryKey dkey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key, false);
    string data = dkey.GetValue("Version").ToString();
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Version registry key