# How to detect IE version inside IE

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

I have toolbar written on C++ that run under Internet Explorer with low rights and I need to detect browser version.

Answers from this topic didn't help me, because I didn't have rights to read HKLM registry tree
[How to get IE version info in Winform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197794/how-to-get-ie-version-info-in-winform)

Only possibility that I see is to make HTTP request that will return User-Agent string in output.

Are there any other abilities to get version?

UPD: I can catch DISPID_BEFORENAVIGATE2 event and retrieve the headers data. This solution require that user made at least one request to web resources

UPD2: If Explorer open about:blank page, then I can catch BEFORENAVIGATE2, but headers data is empty

Comment: Similar to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850709/detecting-which-version-of-ie-is-installed-on-your-os-in-c

Comment: Can you read the file version of MSHTML.DLL?