# In c# get Internet Explorer version and in what update it is

Tags: c#, .net, windows, internet-explorer

How can I know the version of IE and in what update it is? Is there any method?

Comment: access that information in user-agent string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197794/how-to-get-ie-version-info-in-winform

Comment: Check for answer over [here][1] in order to getthe IE version.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6197863/713246

Comment: Also i can find the update somehow, correct?

Comment: What update? Where? A Windows Update? You mean if they have upgraded from IE8 to 9?

Comment: @Bibhu - In comments its `[Text comment](Link)`